# How to include my own method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a method in file lib/my/column.rb

```
module Column
  def array_each_col(num_of_cols, array_arg)
     .. code will return array ..
  end
end
```

And I want to use it in my model

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Column


  def self.my_areas 
     all_areas = Area.all    
     num_of_cols = 2       
     self.array_each_col(num_of_cols, all_areas)
  end
end
```

My application.rb

```
module MyAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
     config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib/my"
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: I will use my method in the different models

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid description of anything. What exactly do you expect to happen, what do you observe? What have you tried to match both? Basically http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: undefined method `array_each_col' for #<Class:0x97365dc>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make module methods available in class methods, you gotta use `extend` rather than `include`

Comment: Works. But what's different between array_each_col and self.array_each_col in this context? works in both cases

Comment: it's the same! you can omit the `self`

Answer (score 0):

try config.autoload_paths << "#{**Rails**.root}/lib/my"